# Achieving horizontal scroll on downward scroll in x-axis overflow (Astro & Tailwind)

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, astrojs

I'm working on a project using Astro and Tailwind, facing a specific challenge with overflow handling. I currently have an overflow set on the x-axis for a design involving cards. However, I'm looking to achieve a unique behavior:

When users scroll down, I want the cards to stack horizontally from left to right within the x-axis overflow, instead of the default horizontal scrolling.

```
---
const bgColors = ["#605C5F", "#494448", "#2D2A2E"];
const bgColor = (index) => bgColors[index % bgColors.length];
const cards = [{ title: "Card 1" }, { title: "Card 2" }, { title: "Card 3" }];
---

<div class="flex overflow-x-auto snap-x snap-mandatory h-screen">
  {
    cards.map((card, index) => (
      <div
        class={`flex flex-shrink-0 justify-center items-center gap-20 h-screen w-screen sticky left-0 snap-center`}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: bgColor(index),
          transform: `translateX(${70 * index}px)`,
        }}
      >
        <h1 class="text-white">{card.title}</h1>
      </div>
    ))
  }
</div>
```

I've tried experimenting with various settings, including overflow properties and scroll behavior adjustments, but haven't achieved the desired outcome.

Could someone please offer guidance or suggest a solution to accomplish horizontal scrolling on a downward scroll within an x-axis overflow using Astro and Tailwind?

I appreciate any insights or assistance you can provide. Thanks in advance!